# Superuser Can't Change User Profile

Tags: user-controls, passwords, joomla3.0

Despite being a Super User (Joomla 3.4), each time I try to modify a user's profile, e.g., edit their name or assign them to a different group, I get this message:

```
The passwords you entered do not match. Please enter your desired password in the password field and confirm your entry by entering it in the confirm password field.
```

I am not entering a password.  It almost looks like Joomla (or my Mac) is autofilling the first password entry and wants me to fill in the confirming password entry.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

delete the auto-filled password and save - this is a browser thing